# When does the rendering update in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, specifications, event-loop, rerender

I was reading [html specs concerning web api's](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model) , and it basically said that

> After the event loop has performed some task from a task queue, it needs to update the rendering (if this is a window event loop)

It is also said that the user agent has some way of telling that updating the render isn't necessary (see point 10.3 "unnecessary rendering" in the link above)

So my question is the following: if, let's say, I have a simple index.html file and only one script file attached to it - index.js

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello StackOverflow
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
function add(a,b) {
    console.log(a+b);
}

function modifyBackground() {
    document.body.style = 'background : red';
}

console.log('Hello world'); // Task 1
add(4,5); // Task 2
modifyBackground(); // Task 3 Will the render be updated only here?
```

I view it that way - there are 3 tasks combined in my index.js. The first task is the `console.log` task,it is first added onto the task queue in the event loop.Then there's the `add` task, and finally the `modifyBackground` task.

In theory, if the user agent doesn't have a way of knowing if we actually need to update the render, it should update the render after every task.

**Will the re-render happen only when I call the `modifyBackground()` method on the last line? And, if so, how  does the user agent tell that the re-render isn't necessary?**

**P.S.** If you want some clarification, I want to know, how does, for example, google chrome's user agent tell that the re-render isn't necesssary.

Comment: which work is necessary for the browser depends on the CSS property that was changed. You can read more about here: https://aerotwist.com/blog/css-triggers/

Does that help?

Comment: @manoi Thanks for a nice article, but it is a bit more about js rather that css. I view it that way - there are 3 tasks combined in my js code, first the console.log task is added onto the task queue in the event loop, then the add task, and finally the modifyBackground task, and in theory, if the user agent doesn't have a way of knowing if we actually need to update the render, it should update the render after every task. P.S. I'll update the answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

> Will the re-render happen only when I call the `modifyBackground()`
>   method on the last line?

It depends on the browser implementation, they do not follow the specs sometimes.

> And, if so, how does the user agent tell that the re-render isn't
>   necessary?

Again, it depends on the browser implementation. You need to understand how a browser rendering works. Here's a great explanation you can check it out: [How the browser renders a Web Page](https://itnext.io/how-the-browser-renders-a-web-page-dom-cssom-and-rendering-df10531c9969). Below is a resume.

There are 3 basic concepts:

1. DOM
2. CSSOM
3. Render Tree.

**Document Object Model (DOM)**

When the browser reads HTML code, whenever it encounters an HTML element like html, body, div etc., it creates a JavaScript object called as Node. Eventually, all HTML elements will be converted to JavaScript objects. Since every different HTML element has different properties, the Node object will be created from different classes (constructor functions).

**CSS Object Model (CSSOM)**

After constructing the DOM, the browser reads CSS from all the sources (external, embedded, inline, user-agent, etc.) and construct a CSSOM. CSSOM stands for CSS Object Model which is a Tree Like structure just like DOM.
Each node in this tree contains CSS style information for that particular DOM element. CSSOM, however, does not contain DOM elements which can’t be printed on the screen like , ,  etc.

**Render Tree**

Here is the answer to your question. Render-Tree is a tree-like structure constructed by combining DOM and CSSOM trees. The browser has to calculate the layout of each visible element and paint them on the screen, for that browser uses Render-Tree. Hence, unless Render-Tree isn’t constructed, nothing will get printed on the screen.

Comment: I know that the implementation differs across the different browsers, but it can't be that drastically different. Just for clarification I updated my answer to ask how does the google chrome user agent work in situations like these.

Comment: The main different is **when** things happen. Chrome for example renders the page while it is loading and each time it encounters the `script` tag the DOM construction is paused. The entire DOM construction process is halted until the script finishes executing.